# how can I back up my contact name list

Tags: contacts

My contacts on my IPhone 4s was lost. If I backed up my phone to the computer, will the contacts also be saved? where can I find that or how can I restore my contact list?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, contacts are saved in iPhone Backups, or in iCloud if you have that enabled.

This Apple support page illustrates restoring backups. http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1766

For restoring computer backups:

1. Connect your iOS device to the computer that has your backup
2. Make sure this computer has the latest version of iTunes
3. Choose File > Devices > Restore from Back up
   If you're using iTunes 10.7 or earlier, right-click the device from the list and choose Restore from Backup.